# GET-SPProduct -Local throwing error

Tags: powershell

Get_SPProduct cmdlets behaving weird:

1. On running GET-SPProduct -Local to one of server in farm throws error

> Get-SPProduct : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   At line:1 char:14
>   + Get-SPProduct <<<<  -Local
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...letGetSPProduct:SpCmdletGetSPProduct)
>   [Get-SPProduct], NullReferenceException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SpCmdletGetSPProduct

1. Unable to get Farm-Level and Server Patch Level information. These commands don't work:

> get-spproduct |get-member 
>   $sp2010 = get-spproduct 
>   $sp2010.servers
>   $sp2010.InstallStatus 
>   $sp2010.RequiredButMissingPatchableUnits
>   $sp2010.RequiredButMissingPatches 
>   $sp2010.RequiredButMissingProducts

Refering :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mutaz/archive/2011/07/22/check-the-build-level-status-of-components-within-your-sharepoint-2010-farm.aspx

Please advice

-prs

Comment: Does Get-SPFarm work? If not, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Run Get-SPProduct on your command line.
If you are listed with multiple products, then use the index for the commands mentioned in the blog.
Eg:

```
PS C:\> $spprod = Get-SPProduct
[If listed with more than one product]
PS C:\> $spprod[0].Servers | select ServerName, Products, InstallStatus

 $spprod[0].Servers | ? { $_.InstallStatus -eq "InstallRequired" } | % { $_.RequiredButMissingPatches }
```

Comment: For GET-SPProduct try with -Server switch instead of -Local.